# how to add value to objects array inside an object firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add custom object to array that is inside a custom object,
I mean I have object task I save him in cloud firestore, now I have few sub-tasks that I want to save them in the task object, but I want to add one each time.

I tried this code below:

```
db.collection(Constants.TASKLIST).document(uid)
    .update("subTasks", FieldValue.arrayUnion(subTask));
```

data struct

http://www.up2me.co.il/v.php?file=2873228.png

this is my Task Object, the Task and subTask are same

public class Task implements Serializable {

```
private String description;
private String deadline;
private ArrayList<Task> subTasks;

public Task(String description, String deadline) {

    this.description = description;
    this.deadline = deadline;
    this.subTasks = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String getDeadline() {
    return deadline;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public ArrayList<Task> getSubTasks() {
    return subTasks;
}

public void setSubTasks(ArrayList<Task> subTasks) {
    this.subTasks = subTasks;
}

public Task(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Task() {}
```

}

but its give me the following error:

Invalid data. Unsupported type:

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to add.  There should be enough information that anyone can reproduce the exact situation.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and the content of your `SubTask` class. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: edit post lllll

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayList contains objects of type Task if I understand correctly.
Firestore only supports a certain amount of data types and that does not seem to be one of them.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjaN4.png) is a list of the the items you can save on the firestore database.

what you could do for example is save the task as a reference or to make it simple just save the id's of the documents as strings in your array.